# Android inapp purchse display wrong product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Hi i am using inapp purchse version 3 in my application.
 download demo from  http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment-v3/ then i had integrate all code in my application change base64key of my application change all permision in manifiest then draft this on devloper consol make inapp purchse product with pro version name and price is 199Rs. Now the problem is that when i am going to purchase from device it's display me Sample Title and price is $0.99. why it's displing sample becuse  i had make product with pro version? it's display like below:

[image]

Comment: May be that your are not passing correct product Id while purchasing from your device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your blundell-app code,

check this line in the blundell document,

> When the PurchasePassportActivity is started, it will get a callback
>   saying billing is available and go onto to purchase the passport. The
>   only thing special in this Activity is that is passed the SKU (the
>   items ID from Google Play) to the Helper service. In this tutorial we
>   use the “android.test.purchased” SKU meaning purchases will always be
>   successful.

While we are setUp for the passport product we are also setting the product id(item id or you can say SKU) in the given method.

```
 @Override protected void dealWithIabSetupSuccess() {
            purchaseItem(Passport.SKU); 
 }
```

> in the passport class we are passing the SKU or product id

**EDIT:**

```
public class Passport {

         public static final String SKU = "your_real_product_id"; // Replace this with your item ID;
     // we are using "android.test.purchased" for testing the billing process
     }
```

As document says change your product id here which is created in the play console.

> "android.test.purchased" is the dummy product id which is used to test
>   purchase flow of the billing application cycle. It will help you to
>   test purchase scenario in your application but with out credit card
>   process. For testing the credit card process you can click on the
>   price 0.99$ given in the dialog and you can find end to end testing
>   with using credit card also.

I would also like to suggest you to implement either original demo given by the google itself.

for [More info](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

**EDIT**

**Product ID:**

> it should be  "NAME/ID" formate like "Product Name(product_id)" you
>   have to choose product_id then according to your reply it should be
>   "proversion" in your case.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: same thing i had do now there is question that why it's display sample title? and sedond thing when i goes to live my app? i have to change sku="android.test.purchsed" ?

Comment: @PintuCorna, Please understand what I am trying to say, you just have to change "your_product_id" instead of "android.test.purchased". We are using "android.test.purchased" for the testing purpose only, after we upload the app on to the play store it will not be required. If you are using the "your_product_id" it will show you your product title and your product description in the dialog. Hope now you understood what I am trying to say.

Comment: check my edited Passport class given in the answer above, if you still  have any problem then please edit your Passport class and other classes code into your question.

Comment: @ Maulik i understand it but confusion is that in my inapp purchas list it display that Purchse Pro Version(proversion) under title name/id so  which i can consider as product id Purchase Pro Version or proversion?

Comment: @PintuCorna Edited in my answer, according to your previous reply it should be "proversion" is your product_id.

Comment: @PintuCorna, Have you get your product title in dialog, let me know.

Comment: ya i got due to miss understanding it's cause proble nothing proble in my code just remaing thing is to change product id it done... Thanks maulik